# Firebase android как удалять данные?

Tags: android, firebase

Как удалить данные из бд в Firebase?

Comment: Задать им значение в виде null

Answer (score 6):

Существует метод [removeValue()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_removeValue) у объекта FireBase:

> Set the value at this location to 'null'
>
> Установите значение в этом месте null

Пример: `myFireBase.setValue(null);`

Comment: спасибо,помогли!